# Changing UILabel's text

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm currently following CS 193P, and I'm on lecture 2.
If you've followed this class before, I'm where we just added a label to output the number of flips.

Here's the screenshot of the view and controller (original code from the lecture):
[image: original code]

I notice the instructor is changing the flipsLabel's text from inside the setter for flipCount. But, I think it's easier/ more intuitive to just send a message to the flipsLabel object whenever touchCardButton method is being called. Here's the screenshot after modification:
[image: after modification]

Can somebody explain the reason why the instructor wrote it that way? He said "And here's another great use of getters and setters, which is to keep UI in sync with a property"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I started my iOS developer career from CS193P as well about 2+ years ago.

Just like KudoCC said above, if you use your method to set `flipCount` in 10 different places, then you will have to set `self.flipsLabel` in 10 different places as well. So, your method will have more lines of code while the professor's way is using less lines of code.

I personally think that it is the art of programming. We have different ways to achieve the same thing in programming. But, the less code you use in programming is usually the better way.

Answer (score 3):

The content of `self.flipsLabel` only depends on `flipCount` property.

You may change the value of `flipCount` at more than one place afterwards, and if you work as the instructor said, you needn't update the content of `self.flipsLabel` every time you change `flipCount`.

You are in a simple user case which may not matter how to implement it, but if you are in a complex user case, you may change the value of `flipCount` at 100 places, in you intuitive way, you must add 100 times `[self.flipsLabel setText:[....]]`, if you forget to add in one place, a bug is born.

Comment: I'm still confused. The message I sent to `self.flipsLabel` is also calling the getter for `flipCount`. Wouldn't that guarantee that it'll give me the most recent value no matter, say the value of `flipCount` is changed in other different places?

Comment: Actually it is the other way round. What you want to achieve here is whenever **flipCount** is set, you will have to set **flipsLabel** as well. So, professor puts the method to set **flipsLabel** inside the setter for **flipCount**. So, whenever **flipCount** is set, **flipsLabel** will be set automatically.

Comment: Oh I see what you say, that's a pretty good trick. It is just professor made this `flipCount` property restricted for `flipsLabel` use only. But, just out of curiosity, isn't the way I did it still legitimate? I mean if professor expects the `flipCount` setter to be called in the first place, isn't it okay if I'm calling the getter instead and get the same result?

Comment: yes, your way is still legit and will get the same result. It is just a different way of programming.

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of his code is: Everytime you set a new value for flipCount property, the text of label also changed. You don't need to set label text again. Your code will be clear, and easy to modify after.